# Clear user defaults of my OS X application after uninstall

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos

I am developing an OS X application on swift, and i have requirement to delete my application's user default preferences after uninstalling it. As i want to clear user preferences on a fresh install of the application. Unlike in iOS, uninstalling the application doesn't clear my application's user defaults in OS X. Currently i know how to delete user defaults programatically but i do not know where to put the below code :-

```
let domain = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!
UserDefaults.standard.removePersistentDomain(forName: domain)
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

Please help on finding the correct trigger point for the above code.

**Edit 1 :** By *Uninstalling* the application, i mean deleting the application (moving to Bin)

Comment: When you say uninstall, do you mean deleting the app from the device ?

Comment: "to delete my application's user default preferences after uninstalling it"  That is not possible.

Comment: @claude31, by uninstall i mean adding the application to bin. As there is no uninstaller for macOS applications

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice it was OSX. My mistake. And do you empty the bin ?

Comment: @claude31 yes i have tried emptying the bin, but it doesn't delete the user defaults in the main bundle. For iOS it does delete automatically after app deletion but not in OS X's case

Comment: @Anshuman How does it effects, after you've moved the app to the bin. Does it affect the new build?

Comment: @Anshuman I too had the same problem. When you delete the app from the launcher, then most of the time the user defaults file is deleted sometime not.
Now changed all values to core data from user defaults. Seems like OS issue.